# CustomListViewAdapter - Button click to affect TextView outside of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a layout which consist of a ListView and a TextView.

On the ListView items, it has one Button. On the Button's onClickListener, is it able to change the text of the TextView that is on the parent layout?

I have set the Button's onClickListener but have not been able to find a way to let the Button change the TextView properties etc.

Thanks! :)

Layout:
[image]

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: @Haresh The code is similar to the bottom code below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you..

**XML** code

**activity**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChnageTextColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Android Demo Text For TextView"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstChangeTextColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

**list_item**
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtColor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"/>

</LinearLayout>

**ACTIVITY** code

**MyActivity**
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private ListView lstChangeTextColor;
    private TextView txtChnageTextColor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        lstChangeTextColor = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstChangeTextColor);
        txtChnageTextColor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtChnageTextColor);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("name", "Red");
        map1.put("value", "#FF0000");
        HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("name", "Orange");
        map2.put("value", "#FFA500");
        HashMap<String,String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3.put("name", "Yellow");
        map3.put("value", "#FFFF00");
        HashMap<String,String> map4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map4.put("name", "Lime");
        map4.put("value", "#00FF00");
        HashMap<String,String> map5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map5.put("name", "Blue");
        map5.put("value", "#0000FF");
        listItem.add(map1);
        listItem.add(map2);
        listItem.add(map3);
        listItem.add(map4);
        listItem.add(map5);
        lstChangeTextColor.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this,listItem));

    }

    class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItem;
        private Context context;
        public ListAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItem) {
            this.listItem = listItem;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listItem.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listItem.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
                holder.txtColor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtColor);
                holder.btnSet = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtColor.setText(listItem.get(position).get("name"));
            holder.btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txtChnageTextColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(listItem.get(position).get("value")));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        Button btnSet;
        TextView txtColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: `txtChnageTextColor` is not declared at all in `BaseAdapter` and my `BaseAdapter` is in a different file. It won't work this way right? Unless I `findViewById` in the `BaseAdapter` file?

Comment: @user2301818,Hi here i declare adapter as inner class so "txtChnageTextColor" scope easily accessible if you declare adapter as separate class then you have to pass reference of "txtChnageTextColor" to adapter class